# Chrome developer tools , React component not showing component structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and i made a simple React app.

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    counter: 0
}
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
      </div>
    );
 }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Output in browser seems to be okay.(React Element has been rendered and it's visible on browser)- DOM elements has been created
but in developer tools in Bookmark Components App is shown with red triangle and you cannot see a structure of component created, hovering on triangle showing message:"This component is not running in strict mode.."
[image]

Should be rather something like that(my tutor screenshot)

[image]

I added strict mode to component in Visual studio code ide  (no result):

```
   <React.StrictMode>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
      </div>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap it around your component causing the issue, not only around a div. There where you call your App component, probably from index.js?

```
  <React.StrictMode>
     <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

And remove all your filters from the settings to show the structure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That removed warning but I still can't see what is inside App in Components Bookmark(div and h1)

Answer (score 0):

Hi use react developer Tools extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Vijay but  that has been already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install react developer tools in your browser and enable it.

Here is a link for the tool for google chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question came up as a response to my query for the search "react component not showing structure." Hard reset with cache clear as referenced here: [react-devtools : Timeout unable to inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897741/react-devtools-timeout-unable-to-inspect-element/76415027#76415027) did solve the problem temporarily as promised.

Today React recognized the issue and I got a prompt in dev tools which sent me here and solved my issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-devtools/README.md#the-react-tab-shows-no-components.